# UIView 3D transform final frame location

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I have a UIView which has an X origin that makes it off screen to the right. Then, I do a keyframe animation with CATransform3D:

```
[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-view.width, 0, 0)]
```

The problem is, after the animation completes, the view's frame is visually in the correct place, but it still thinks it's off screen, so I can't interact with it. Logging its frame property also shows that it's offscreen, but visually, it's not.

The fill mode for the animation is `kCAFillModeForwards`, so the final value of the animation sticks.

What is the solution to this problem, that is, interacting with this view after the animation and notifying the view that it is indeed visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAAnimation delegate method `-animationDidStop:finished:` to fix it when the animation done:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better answer is to use UIView animation methods like animateWithDuration:animations:completion: (and variants on that method.)

Those methods let you do animations on the actual view properties, and when the animation is complete, the view is at it's actual destination location.

The center property is the easiest way to move views around. The frame property isn't valid if you've applied a transform, but the center property IS always valid for both reading and writing.

Core Animation only creates the illusion that your views move. The animation takes place on a display-only copy of the layer tree. You can query the properties of an animating layer by reading those same properties from the layer's presentationLayer. However, the view objects will not respond to the user interaction at their apparent location. The views still think they are at their original locations.

As the other poster said, you could use the animation completion delegate method to move the view to it's final location once the animation is over, but that's a lot of fussy work to do something that UIView animation does for you much more cleanly and simply.

Comment: I'm doing an advanced key-frame animation, so simple UIView animations wouldn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you interact with the view even before you animate it? 
is the  view.userInteractionEnabled  is set to YES??